# Apply an equation on a dataframe order by date in r

Tags: r, dataframe, equation

This is how my data looks like:

```
structure(list(ID = c("h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01"), collection_date = structure(c(15076, 
15076, 15092, 15092, 15125), class = "Date"), wavelength = c(630L, 
800L, 630L, 800L, 630L), R = c(0.078, 0.295, 0.108, 0.361, 0.127
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm want to do (but have no idea) is to apply the following equation:
"(`R` of the `wavelength` 800 - `R` of the `wavelength` 630) / (`R` of the `wavelength` 800 + `R` of the `wavelength` 630)" per each individual `collection_date` and return the result in an individual dataframe.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For dates with only a single wavelength, what do you prefer as output

Comment: They are all in pairs, that was my fault to do `dput(head(h01_specveg_data_spectra,5))` instead `dput(head(h01_specveg_data_spectra,6))`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `arrange` the data by 'ID', 'collection_date', 'wavelength', then grouped by 'ID', 'collection_date', get the `diff` of 'R' and divide by the `sum` (assuming only 800 and 630 `wavelength` present).  If there is only a single observation, return `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter(wavelength %in% c(800, 630)) %>% # in case there are other wav
     arrange(ID, collection_date, wavelength) %>%
     group_by(ID, collection_date) %>% 
     summarise(new = if(n() == 1) NA_real_ else diff(R)/sum(R), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ID    collection_date    new
  <chr> <date>           <dbl>
1 h01   2011-04-12       0.582
2 h01   2011-04-28       0.539
3 h01   2011-05-31      NA
```

Comment: Since I have all pairs can I ignore the last line "`summarise(new = if(n() == 1) NA_real_ else diff(R)/sum(R), .groups = 'drop')`"?

Comment: @CláudioSiva yes, you can just do `summarise(diff(R)/sum(R), .groups = 'drop')`

Answer (score 1):

You may write a function to perform the calculation with the help of `match` and apply if for each `ID` and `collection_date`.

```
library(dplyr)

result_calc <- function(wave, R) {
  r1 <- R[match(630, wave)]
  r2 <- R[match(800, wave)]
  (r2 - r1)/(r2 + r1)
}

df %>%
  group_by(ID, collection_date) %>%
  summarise(result = result_calc(wavelength, R), .groups = 'drop')

#   ID    collection_date result
#  <chr> <date>           <dbl>
#1 h01   2011-04-12       0.582
#2 h01   2011-04-28       0.539
#3 h01   2011-05-31      NA
```